# Hibernate's @Version vs transactions

Tags: hibernate

Could someone please explain me why we should use @Version annotation in Hibernate while we already use transactions? Does not transactions guarantees database consistency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to read the *JavaDoc* of `@Version`:

> The version is used to ensure integrity when performing the merge operation and for optimistic concurrency control.

And (if you don't know it) the *JavaDoc* of `EntityManager.merge()`:

> Merge the state of the given entity into the current persistence context.

Which means to add an entity that is *not* part of a transaction to that transaction.

To say it in other words: A transaction is used to check consistency for short running operations while `@Version` is used for long running (*detached*) operations, e.g. when editing an entity across multiple server requests.